# Can't access an object through its name as a string

Tags: javascript, variables

I try to find out, how it is possible to access an object through a string which has the same name as the object name. Is there any specific notations for the string to be interpreted as the object name?

Like in my example script:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var door = {"opened":false, "window":{"opened":false} };

            function knocking(event){
               var knockedThing = event.target.id;

             alert(knockedThing);
             alert("door is opened : " + knockedThing.opened);
             alert("door window is opened : " + knockedThing.window.opened);
            }
        </script>

        <button id="door" onclick="knocking(event)">A door</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

The script can be run here:
---> https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FX3JE6FP2UFQ

The goal of my script is to use the id "door" of the clicked button to access the object "door".
But right now it doesn't work because the button id "door" is just a string name which have nothing to do with the object with same name.

How it is possible to make the connection without creating an object which would integrate the object "door" (to make this one accessible through the brackets notation)?

```
var house = {"door":{"opened":false, "window":{"opened":false} } };
```

Which would be accessible through bracket notation, like this:

```
alert(house[something]);
alert("door is opened : " + house[something].opened);
alert("door window is opened : " + house[something].window.opened);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var door = {"opened":false, "window":{"opened":false} };

            function knocking(event){
                var knockedThing = event.target.id;

             alert(knockedThing);
             alert("door is opened : " + window[knockedThing].opened);
             alert("door window is opened : " + window[knockedThing].window.opened);
            }
        </script>

        <button id="door" onclick="knocking(event)">A door</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Global variables are properties of the `window` object, so you can access `door` through `window['door']`.

Comment: Thanks Melpomene!
I am not realy sure to understand what you mean. Isn't your solution what I am also suggesting thru my `house[something]` example in the second part of my message?

What I would like to know is if there is a solution without to have to use the `[ ]` notation. But maybe it's not possible

Comment: @mosis Why do you not want to use `[` `]`?

Comment: Hi, because I found more clear and confortable to access the object `door` directly by inputing `door` instead to have to create a parent object including my `door`object as property. And then to have to input `parentObject[door]` to acces it. And then I think I can't pass `parentObject[door]` directly as parameter in function(or can I ?)

Comment: @mosis Why do you think you need to create a parent object? Did you not read my answer?

Comment: Hi melpomene, I do read your answer wich is working well. Maybe "parent object" is not the correct term to express that the variable `parentObject` is including `door` (making `door` a kind of child, by becoming a property). I don't know, as I am not an experienced programmer, I was thinking that working without `[ ]` if possible, would help to maintain my script clean.

Comment: @mosis I don't understand. The code in my answer uses `[ ]`, but there is no explicit parent object. It's just `var door = ...`. How is this not exactly what you wanted?

Comment: Hi melpomene, the goal of my original script was to use the id named `"door"` of the clicked button to direct access the object called also `door`. To make it simple.

Comment: But it seems that the name `"door"` of the id remains understood as an id content so that when I assign it as value to variable `knockedThing` the following line `alert("door is opened : " + knockedThing.opened);` in my script won't be understand as `alert("door is opened : " + door.opened);`. As I got the alert popup "door is opened: undefined".

Comment: That why I asked if there was any tricks to make `"door"` understandable as a string or something else, that works. I tried to convert the id `"door"` assigned to `knockedThing` as a string thru `toString()` before reassign it in `alert("door is opened : " + knockedThing.opened);` but it didn't work.

So in the end only the way with `[ ]`works.